# How do I insert a partial into a rails_admin view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin

I would like to add a partial to the default show and edit pages of one of my models in rails_admin. Is there a way to do this without completely customizing those views?

Comment: I do not get it what you want to do, writing <%= render 'partial_name' %> in both the pages will include that partial in both the pages.

Comment: By any chance you are talking about including a layout?

Comment: Not a layout. I don't want to have to re-create the views from hand, just include a custom partial.